# How to know whether there is a vertex called 'A' with data in it?

Tags: node.js, gremlin, janusgraph

[image]Actually I want to test my query on console. For that I need static data. Can I know that there is a data present or not in a particular vertex. If not I am able to keep the static data but in my vertex, I have property called 'location' which is of 'point'. 
So while giving static data to location I have to specify the latitude and longitude.

here the location property is having type point. IF i meant to keep static data, I have to pass only one variable. But how to get the point using latitude and longitude?

Thanks in advance.

```
g.V().hasLabel('A').has('location','.....').valueMap()
```

Comment: what graph database are you using?

Comment: sorry i am using janus graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create a `Point` then:

```
g.addV('A').property('location',Geoshape.point(37.97, 23.72))
```

You can read more about `GeoShape` [here](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/search-predicates.html#geoshape).

If you need to check if a vertex has a "location" property then:

```
g.V().hasLabel('A').has('location')
```

Comment: ,can you help me with this error                                                                             
Value [(Geoshape.point( 17.3999,78.5601)).getPoint()] is not an instance of the expected data type for property key [location] and cannot be converted. Expected: class org.janusgraph.core.attribute.Geoshape, found: class java.lang.String

Comment: you get this error in the Gremlin Console executing the traversal i posted above?

Comment: yes I am getting this error while i am adding a vertex through gremlin console. I have tried Geoshape.point(..,..) and Geoshape.point(..,..).getPoint(). But ended up with this error.

Comment: Perhaps you have something wrong in your schema definition for "location". Note that in the example `GraphOfTheGodsFactory` their "place" property is established like this: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/b44b20a6c31fff84772f7a4a95159db24fa09381/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java#L92 and they insert data just as i wrote in my answer: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/b44b20a6c31fff84772f7a4a95159db24fa09381/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java#L142-L144

Comment: Inserted data worked fine Geoshape.point( 17.3999f,78.5601f).

Comment: I have also tried Geoshape.point(float 17.3999,float 78.5601). But I got above error.

Comment: Geoshape.point( 17.3999f,78.5601f) and  Geoshape.point(float 17.3999,float 78.5601) are similar. But can I know why second attempt is not successful.

Comment: the second is not validate groovy or java, but i would think you could do: `Geoshape.point((float) 17.3999, (float) 78.5601)`